# Display rooms and count user in each one with simple Sql query

Tags: sql, count

what i want to achieve is this

i got 2 table `table 1 = users` `table 2 = rooms`

what i try to do is to get a list of all room but at same time get how many user that are in that specific room.

table rooms contain

```
id | name | description | limit
```

table users contain

```
roomid | username | password
```

at the end i want to display something like this

```
room 1 | description | numberofuser / limit
```

Thanks for any help

currently what i am using to do this is i repeat a query inside a while but if i have 100 rooms then it will make 100 sql query everytime i display the list

Comment: Use an aggregation query with count and group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your database and this query works.

```
    SELECT room.id, room.name,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE room.id=user.roomid)
AS "Occupancy"
  FROM room;
```

Note: My standard is to use singular names for tables (user rather than users) and I called my key to room in the user table"roomid", but you can use yours of course.

Here is the result:

```
id  Name        Occupancy   
1   PentHouse   4
2   basement    5
3   MeetingRoom 0
```

You can add limit to the field list. I didn't replicate that.

Comment: This is a bit shorter than some suggestions and it gives the computed column (the count) a meaningful name.

Comment: yes that is shorter and do exact same thing as i was looking for thanks

Answer (score 0):

First get the count using `GROUP BY` and then perform a `JOIN`

```
select r.name,
r.description,
xx.numberofuser_perRoom
from rooms r
join (select roomid, count(*) as numberofuser_perRoom
       from users
       group by roomid) xx on r.id = xx.roomid;
```

Comment: i wonder if this will work

`SELECT
 rooms.name,
 rooms.description,
 rooms.roomid, 
 ( SELECT Count(users.id) FROM users  Where users.roomid = rooms.roomid ) as room_count  
FROM  rooms 
ORDER BY name ASC`

Comment: @Mireille28, don't wonder and try it out. Fireup the query and see for yourself. That's how you will learn.

Comment: yes sorry i am new here and still do not understand how you guys show code like this with blue text on many lines but i will figure it out

Comment: @Mireille28, that's code formatting. use `{}` icon in editor to format code.

Comment: thanks very helpfull and fast help that solve a problem i had for long time i didnt wanted to ask for help and try to solve it by myself but i gived up after a week

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specify which DB is that for, nor whether you want to see rows for empty rooms (i assumed yes), so it could look something like this:

```
SELECT r.name, r.description, COUNT(u.username) * 100. / r.limit 
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.roomid = r.id
GROUP BY r.name, r.description, r.limit
```